# How to build a function that shows a number changed using a max distance between them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits, functions, arithmetic, interval-arithmetic

I stuck in some problem, lets say I have:

- the max distance between two numbers are 5 (difference)
- x is an integer greater than 1
- w is an unique integer number generated by function f
- z is an unique integer number generated by function f and is different from w

---

E.G.:

f(x) = w

f(x+1) = w

...

f(x+maxDistance) = z (the number has changed because x+maxDistance is greater or equal than 5)

---

*Note: the input values (x, x+1, and x+maxDistance) don't know each other, I want to use the return value to check if the number surpassed the value only using the return of function.

---

A real example to give more context to my problem, I have a chronometer that is counting the time:

In a certain moment, it is showing the number 4

In another moment, it shows the number 6 (2 seconds elapsed)

So I want to make a function with that conditions:

f(4) = 1

f(6) = 1 ( 6-4 <= 5 ? true )

...

f(10) = 2  (10-4 <= 5 ? false)

See that the return value changed 1 to 2? Thats what I want, the input numbers don't know each other, 1 and 2 can be x and y but they must be different.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lulu, the question is: how to build a function that follow the conditions I put in the description, I will change the question to sounds like a inquiry.

Comment: You can't think of a function that produces different values for different arguments?

Comment: @lulu, a function cant return equal values using different inputs? its a function prerequisite?

Comment: Of course it can.  Constant functions are still functions.  if $f(x)=x^2$ then $f(1)=f(-1)$.

Comment: None of this is at all clear.  Presumably you are given some sort of data.  What sort of data are you given?  What information do you have about it?  What is it you want to do with that data?

Comment: @lulu, ok, I understood, but in my case, i want to make a function that return the same value only in certain condition, the value of input cant surpass the max difference between two numbers, if it surpass the return value must be different, I don't know if i'm confused with this problem.

Comment: @lulu, I will edit my question to make a practical example to clarify what I want, the problem I showed is too abstract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127575/discussion-between-gilt-goose-and-lulu).